# How do we talk about conservation of energy when the potential field keeps changing with time?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservative-field

The way it is taught in school, you have a mass moving under the influence of an unchanging potential field. It can be proven that if the mass moves from point A to point B in the field, the increase in its kinetic energy can be calculated by simply subtracting the scalar valued potentials at the two points. So there is a number you can calculate at any instant : KE+PE. This number is always found to be the same.

But this logic really restricts the idea of conservation of energy. In the real world, it's the masses which produce the potential fields around them. Potential fields don't just exist on their own. So if we have two objects moving under the influence of each others' gravity, the potential fields created by them keep changing with time.

And all the fundamental interactions are not as simple as gravity or Coloumb force. There's also magnetic forces which depend on speed, and nuclear/weak forces (I don't know the mathematical expressions for these). These forces might not be gradients of some potential field.

It seems like, with all these complications, we'd no longer be able to speak about the constancy of the number KE+PE in advanced Physics (as it wouldn't be constant in the real world). But we still do talk about conservation of energy in higher level physics as if it still remains a fundamental law. How do people re-define or modify this quantity so that it's still a conserved number even with all these complications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conservation of energy always holds for an entire system. If we have a particle in a changing potential the *total* energy of the entire system (particle + whatever's creating the potential) is constant.

If we take two containers of water, $A$ and $B$, the total amount of water in both containers is constant no matter how much we transfer the water between them (assuming no leaks). However, if water is allowed to flow between them and we only consider the total amount of water in container $B$ rather than both of them we might be misled to believe that the total amount of water is not conserved.

This is analogous to considering a particle in a static potential (water not allowed to flow, in which case "conservation of the total amount of water" and "conservation of the amount of water in $B$" are effectively the same statement) vs considering a particle in a changing potential (water is allowed to flow, total amount of water in $B$ is *not* conserved, however the total amount in $A+B$ *is* conserved).

Comment: Okay. So we just have to sum up the PE and KE of both objects to find the conserved number. Though how do we adapt this principle to magnetic, nuclear, weak interactions? Gravity and Coloumb forces are gradient of a scalar field, but magnetic forces depend on velocity.

Comment: @RyderRude Magnetic fields do no work. So for example a charged particle in a constant magnetic field will just go in a circle and not speed up, so its Kinetic energy will be conserved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion comes from the distinction between partial derivatives and total derivatives. I.e. there is a difference between potentials that have the form $V(x(t))$ and $V(x(t), t)$--the latter has an *explicit* time dependence not coming from the motion of the particle. For example, to show the conservation of energy with a system with only transnational motion and under a potential with no explicit time dependence:

$\frac{d}{dt}E = \frac{d}{dt}(K_E+V(x(t)))=m\dot{x}\ddot{x}+(\nabla V)\dot{x} = 0$

where the last equality is by Newton's second law. But if you made the potential *explicitly* dependent on time, you would get an additional term due to the chain rule:

$\frac{d}{dt}E = \frac{d}{dt}(K_E+V(x(t),t))=m\dot{x}\ddot{x}+(\nabla V)\dot{x} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$

and this last expression has no real reason to be zero.

**Note:** If you know a bit of Lagrangian mechanics, another way to say this is that if our system has no explicit time dependence, then we have a continuous symmetry in time; thus by Noether's theorem we know we have a conserved quantity. We call this conserved quantity energy.